# Make two matrices perpendicular by orthogonal transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonal-matrices

I have a $d\times d$ rank-1 matrix $A$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ of the same dimension with non-negative diagonal entires, and I want to find two orthogonal matrices $S_1$ and $S_2$ in $O(d)$ such that:
$\mathrm{trace(AS_1DS_2)}=0$.

The pair $(S_1,S_2)$ is not unique, consider for example $S_2=I_d$ be the identity matrix and decompose $A$ as $A=v_1v_2^T$. Now we want $S_1$ to make the vectors $Dv_1$ and $v_2$ perpendicular, for which there is infinite solutions $(d\geq 3)$.

I would like to find all such pairs if possible.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! We are expecting from OP that to share what OP have tried.

Comment: Hi @beingmathematician. Thanks for your message. Could you elaborate more on what you mean by what OP have tried?

Comment: In the last paragraph you said "I would like to find all such pairs if possible" what have you tried to answer your question?

Comment: The only case I know how to solve is when we set either S_1 or S_2 to identity (as discussed), which simplifies the problem into finding a rotation/reflection matrix that makes two vectors perpendicular (for which exists infinite solutions).
I would like to find all such orthogonal matrices, not just the case when we set one of them to identity.